# What is/are the possible (adverbial) conjunction(s) for the target participle expression?

Tags: participle-clauses

Is the italicized part a participle? And what is its corresponding conjunction?

I feel like the participle here serves to add background or supplementary information to the subject in the main clauses. But I am sure which subordinator or preposition can be used to turn it back to an adverbial clause.

***First introduced in the 1940 Disney movie Pinocchio***, the song tells us, "If your heart is in your dreams, no request is too extreme."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the bolded portion is a participle phrase or clause (depending on your grammatical sect).

And Yes, the clause is supplementary to the main clause.

But you cannot "turn it back to an adverbial clause" because it does not act as an adverbial—that is, it does not modify a constituent which acts as a verb, adjective or adverb. It modifies a noun phrase, *the song*, and thus acts as an adjectival.

To turn this into a full dependent clause you would employ a relativizing "conjunction", which would require placing at after the nominal it modifies:

> The song, ***which was*** first introduced in the 1940 Disney movie Pinocchio, tells us &c

Or you could, by appropriating its subject from the main clause and providing a copula, promote it to a full independent clause juxtaposed to the main clause or joined to the main clause with a "co-ordinating conjunction such as *and* or a semicolon, which would require filling the subject slot of the original main clause:

> ***The song was*** first introduced in the 1940 Disney movie Pinocchio; **it** tells us &c

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking about the possibility that it can be a reduced relative clause, acting as an adjectival phrase modifying the noun "the song". If it is the case, what I am not sure about is whether a reduced relative clause, can be repositioned clause-initially from the position after the modified (the subject "the song" in this case).

Comment: @Stephen_steven Yes. Your original does exactly that.

Comment: So, is it ok to put a reduced RC in the clause-initial position rather than after the noun being modified? (Since in grammar books, I only see reduced RCs after nouns they modify) 
Or is it possible that "First introduced in the 1940" is a participle phrase, i.e., an adverbial phrase, such that it can be moved more flexibly to the clause initial position? And the original potential reading is similar to "With the song being first introduced in the 1940, the song tells us, "If your heart is in your dreams, no request is too extreme." ?